# Issue integrating robot-framework with KiwiTCMS

Tags: robotframework, kiwi-tcms

Am exploring kiwiTCMS, Trying to Integrate robot-framework with KiwiTCMS

Goal: Update Robot framework test-case execution status in KIWITCMS

1. Created a KIWITCMS account and Signed In (https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org/)
2. Created a couple of Test-cases under a test plan
3. pip install kiwitcms-robotframework-plugin
4. Did not find Minimal config file ~/.tcms.conf. Hence created using below command
   nano .tcms.conf and added below to the file and saved.

[tcms]

url = https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org/

username = ********

password = ********

5)Created a sample .robot script with the below code

*** Settings ***
Documentation   An example test suite
Library         OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${plan_id}      5603

*** Test Cases ***
Scenario Maps To Existing TestCase
[Tags]    TC-13407  arbitrary_tag_here
Should Be Equal    "Hello"    "Hello"

6. Executed the below command
   robot --listener zealand.listener.KiwiTCMS Tests/Kiwi.robot

## helloworld robot --listener zealand.listener.KiwiTCMS Tests/Kiwi.robot

## Kiwi :: An example test suite

### [ ERROR ] Calling method 'start_suite' of listener 'zealand.listener.KiwiTCMS' failed: ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for public.tenant.kiwitcms.org/: 403 Forbidden>
[ ERROR ] Calling method 'end_test' of listener 'zealand.listener.KiwiTCMS' failed: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Scenario Maps To Existing TestCase                                    | PASS |

How to fix the error?

Comment: you are getting 403 http error. It typically means that your authentication has failed. I'd make a wild guess that if your url points to ` https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org/` - that is not the url where the RPC endpoint is listening and thus, server returns you 403..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How to identify the end point URL?

Answer (score 1):

You have not posted the entire Python traceback so I can't be sure if that's the same issue but basically upgrade to the latest version of this plugin.

For more info:
https://github.com/kiwitcms/robotframework-plugin#v112-15-may-2022 and
https://github.com/kiwitcms/tcms-api/#v112-15-may-2022

403 means you don't have permissions and the API method which returns this is `User.filter`. For security reasons viewing other user accounts requires extra permissions (https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#managing-permissions) which for the same reason are not applied to accounts on public.tenant.kiwitcms.org.

The updated versions work around this by not calling this particular API method unless `${build_user_email}` is specified. And will also silently ignore 403s as well.

*Disclaimer: this answer has been provided by a Kiwi TCMS core team member!*